# how to Serialize List of objects in wcf using linq to sql

Tags: wcf-data-services, wcf-binding

I have built up the wcf web service in visual studio express 2010. I am using Linq to Sql to manipulate with database. where as i am having the tables EmpMaster (primary key table)and EmpDetail (F key table) with relationship based on EmpID. 
I deployed this web service locally as of now. and trying to access the Employee master data as well as detail data using Linq to sql Query in my web application. my web application is MVC based application. whereas Employee master data I can access in web app via web service. but it should load with employee details entries by default.as by default **`DeferredLoadingEnabled`**  is enabled. I can see the set of records in the web service while debugging web service. but while accessing emp detail list data in web application I am getting error. as

```
"the underlying connection was closed the connection was closed unexpectedly "
```

I added in client web config :

```
<binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IEmployeeManagerService"  openTimeout="10:10:00" receiveTimeout="10:10:00" sendTimeout="10:10:00"
      allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
      maxBufferSize="104857600" maxBufferPoolSize="104857600" maxReceivedMessageSize="104857600"
      messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered"
      useDefaultWebProxy="true">
       <readerQuotas maxDepth="104857600" maxStringContentLength="104857600"
                     maxArrayLength="104857600" maxBytesPerRead="104857600" maxNameTableCharCount="104857600" />

       </binding>
```

What should be the problem?

```
   **`**Edited:**`** 

Public Function GetEmployeeDetail(ByVal id As String) As EmployeeDetail Implements IEmployeeManagerService.GetEmployeeDetail
    Dim _empDetail As New EmployeeDetail()
    If Not id Is Nothing Then
        _empDetail = _dbContext.EmployeeDetails.Where(Function(e) e.EmpId = id ).FirstOrDefault()
    End If
    Return _empDetail
End Function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

wel..wel..wel.... Found the trick but cold not get answer. I removed the Mapping between EmpMaster and EmpDetail then regenerate the .dbml. working perfect every thing at least for this time. but as i tried in normal asp.net web service, I got serialization error for EmpMaster object. and error was saying Circular reference ... bla bla bla.. don't know why. as i checked in Database Context class there were nothing seems like that. then i tried by removing the mapping between both tables in sql server. sounds working for me.
... Second way is [here](http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2007/Sep/02/LINQ-to-SQL-and-Serialization)

Answer (score 1):

Well, Deferred Loading (or Lazy Loading) means, in your case, that the EmpDetail datas are retrieved only when you "call" them.

So you retrieve EmpMaster datas, and when you use a property master.EmpDetail.Name, for example, a new request will be sent to database to get the EmpDetail corresponding to the master's EmpDetail.

Of course, the Database must be available (context still alive).

You can see the EmpDetail datas while debugging : when you try to look at the navigation properties of your entity in Debug, it will also query the database to get the values.

To avoid these problems, you can "manually" eager load the datas you know you will need (by the way, you will avoid multiple call to database, if you know you will need all these datas later on).

To to that, you can use the

`Include()` extension.

```
context.EmpMaster.Include("EmpDetail").Where...
```

or select the values you need in an object (anonymous or not)

```
your query.Select(m => new {
   m.Name,
   m.EmpDetail.Propertyx,
 ...
 });
```

**EDIT** :

Right. I'm used to Linq to entities and c#, and you use Linq to SQL and vb.net.

So no way to use `Include()`, but maybe `LoadWith()`

If you have a "Status" property in your "EmployeeDetail" class, you could maybe try something like that.

```
Public Function GetEmployeeDetail(ByVal id As String) As EmployeeDetail Implements IEmployeeManagerService.GetEmployeeDetail
    Dim _empDetail As New EmployeeDetail()
    If Not id Is Nothing Then
         Dim dlo As DataLoadOptions = New DataLoadOptions()
         dlo.LoadWith(Of EmployeeDetails)(Function(e As EmployeeDetails) e.Status)
         _dbContext.LoadOptions = dlo
        _empDetail = _dbContext.EmployeeDetails.Where(Function(e) e.EmpId = id ).FirstOrDefault()
    End If
    Return _empDetail
End Function
```

If you ain't got a "Status" property, you should make an inner join. 
Same idea for EmpMaster and EmployeeDetail

Comment: Thanks , but when i am trying to access the Employee Detail single object only, I am getting the same error. since I am having web method   GetEmployeeDetail(EmpID) which returns the EmpployeeDetial object from web service. I can see data in web service while debugging it. but while transferring this single object only from web service to web application, it encounters Same error given in question. does this means EmployeeDetail Object is not able to serialized while transfer ?

Comment: @ Raphaël Althaus : got issue ? would you suggest for this ?

Comment: @RedSwan You have "underlying connection" problem with EmployeeDetail ? You use pure data from EmployeeDetail or are they also linked with other entities ?

Comment: @ Raphaël Althaus : yes, Employee Details is in relationship with Status Entity. but i guess that should not affect. could not get abiut "pure data from Employee Detail" and what should be the problem with underlaying connection. I prepared the .dbml by drag drop tables from server explorer to .dbml file.

Comment: @RedSwan : if you try to get Status data from EmployeeDetail in your WebService, it will fail. You'll have to make an Include("Status") as well. Could you show your `GetEmployeeDetail(EmpID)` method ?

Comment: @ Raphaël Althaus :added method code in Question. and as i tried to use "Include" , _dbContext.EmployeeDetails.Include ??? does not support. I think it is supports only for Linq to Entity framework. but it should not matters for only return EployeeDetail object .

Comment: @RedSwan you're right. Maybe Edit can help you, but... this isn't my world ;)

Comment: Well, Thanks for discussion and helping me for proper question.